# Incongruent results in Matasano challenge 6 in Go

Tags: xor, vigenere

I'm having some problem in the Matasano challenge [number 6](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6) (the *breaking repeating key-XOR* one)

I'm using Go and for the other challenges I have used a map with the `char` as key and the frequency as `value`

```
func findKeyElement(ct []byte) ([]byte, byte) {

    ot := map[string]float64{"e": 13, "t": 9.1, "a": 8.2, "o": 7.5, "i": 7, "n": 6.7, "s": 6.3, "h": 6.1, "r": 6, "d": 4.3,
        "l": 4, "u": 2.8, "c": 2.8, "m": 2.4, "w": 2.4}

    TopScore, newScore := -1.0, 0.0
    var text, decrText []byte
    var key byte

    for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
        text = singleByteXor(ct, byte(i))
        newScore = calculateScore(text, ot)
        if newScore > TopScore {
            TopScore = newScore
            decrText = text
            key = byte(i)
        }
    }

    return decrText, key
}

func calculateScore(text []byte, ot map[string]float64) float64 {
    score := 0.0

    for i := range text {
        score += ot[string(text[i])]
    }

    return score
}
```

and I'm having good results in all the previous challenges

In this one you have to brake the ciphertext into `KeySize` chunks and break them grouping by column (since the char of the key is the same, treating it like a single byte xor)

---

Using the same technique I got the following key

> Ter(inator X bring the noise

So I basically got it, except for the first `m`. Probably it is due to the fact that the associated column has a lot of special chars like `" "` or `" ' "`, in fact tuning the map frequency adding them I get the correct key. Is there a way to recognize it and avoid tuning manually the occurrences map?

Thank in advance

Comment: In your first loop, doesn't $i$ only go up to 254 (<255)?

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't change the result fixing it